# Apache + Phusion Passenger. Ubuntu 18.04. passenger process getting killed after working several hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have RoR app with apache + passenger 6.0.4 setup. Hosted by DigitalOcean.
It worked as expected for about 6 months but recently it started failing with "Internal Server Error" from the apache side every few hours. It starts working correctly after restarting apache.

In the digital ocean, I can see that CPU starts spinning up to 100% very often when this error started appearing.[cpu metric screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNs8Q.jpg)

In apache error.log file I can see this error appears with every request to server:

```
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to the Passenger core at unix:/root/passenger/passenger.V1HJ9DZ/agents.s/core
  Backtrace:
     in 'Passenger::FileDescriptor Passenger::Apache2Module::Hooks::connectToCore()' (Hooks.cpp:343)
     in 'int Passenger::Apache2Module::Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:622)
```

I haven't found any specific errors in error.log file before these errors starts appearing.

When this is happening there are no Passenger processes in the apache status page.
passenger-status shows this error:

```
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:

1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command-line argument. If so, please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to that directory and run passenger-status again.
2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command-line argument.
```

I already have tried these solutions:

1. Moving `PassengerRegistryDir` from */tmp* to */root/passenger*.
   I checked passenger files: they aren't getting cleared so there is no problem with them.
   When I manually remove these files I get the same error but Passenger processes are running.
2. Enabling `mod_evasive` to protect the server from dos attacks.
3. Setting `PassengerPoolIdleTime 0`
4. Checking rails log files — no specific errors.

I think that somehow the passenger process is getting killed by the system or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days we figured out that our web server was under ddos attack + crypto mining malware.

fail2ban helped with ddos.
clamscan with malware.